# Reduce build time in GitOps by using Docker image layers from previous build with Azure Registry

Tags: github-actions, azure-container-registry

I'm building a Docker Image on Pull Requests in my Github Actions setup. The images are built and pushed to Azure Container Registry. Often, it's only a small update in the code, and if I could reuse the layers from the previous build (pushed to ACR), I could save a lot of time.

As shown in Dockerfile, `yarn install` could be skipped, since new changes occur in the `COPY` statement below it only:

```
FROM node:16

# create dirs and chown
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/node-app && chown -R node:node /usr/src/node-app

WORKDIR /usr/src/node-app

COPY package.json yarn.lock tsconfig.json ./

USER node

# install node modules
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile

# ensure ownership
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# set default env
RUN mv .env.example .env

EXPOSE 3001

# entrypoint is node
# see https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docker-entrypoint.sh

# default command: prod start
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

How can I download the previous image from ACR and use the layers there? Simply downloading the previous image (with different tag) does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the `--cache-from` flag to the `docker build` command if you want to use the downloaded image as cache source.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options